# custom fonts in email are not been displayed

Tags: css, fonts

I am importing 'Roboto' fonts on my sass file

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300";

.email-container {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

The same email works in my machine in chrome gmail, but it doesn't work in some of my colleagues.

Could it be from some kind of their settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email clients are very cautious with loading external content. Most clients are outdated and rely on html4.

Css in some clients isn't parsed either. This could be the reason that the font isn't imported.

To fix this you could use inline style attributes but you won't be able to load a custom font. At least you will have a decent looking email.